# Kibana Generates Constant Stream of Errors

Tags: typescript, elasticsearch, webpack, yarnpkg, kibana-7

I am new to Kibana, Webpack and Yarn.  I am trying to get an existing application to run.  When I do yarn kibana-src, the application gets to "Bundling" and then a constant stream of errors is generated until VS Code crashes.  All of the errors are coming from kibana and not sure what is wrong.  Below is a sample of the errors generated-

```
ERROR in C:\Users\cawoo\Repos\ws03-aac-dashboard02262020\diamond\kibana\src\dev\build\lib\scan_copy.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\cawoo\Repos\ws03-aac-dashboard02262020\diamond\kibana\src\dev\build\lib\scan_copy.test.ts(110,3)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

ERROR in C:\Users\cawoo\Repos\ws03-aac-dashboard02262020\diamond\kibana\src\dev\build\lib\scan_copy.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\cawoo\Repos\ws03-aac-dashboard02262020\diamond\kibana\src\dev\build\lib\scan_copy.test.ts(115,1)
      TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

ERROR in C:\Users\cawoo\Repos\ws03-aac-dashboard02262020\diamond\kibana\src\dev\build\lib\scan_copy.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\cawoo\Repos\ws03-aac-dashboard02262020\diamond\kibana\src\dev\build\lib\scan_copy.test.ts(130,3)
```

All of the errors seem to be typescript related.  Any ideas?